# C++ pointer to string type segmentation fault

Tags: c++

I initialize a pointer to string type and allocate some memory with malloc function. My problem is when i try to use one of the string pointed by this pointer, i get segmentation fault.

```
string anyString = "anyWords";
string *pointerToString;
pointerToString = (string *) malloc(sizeof(string) * 5);
pointerToString[i] = anyString; // this line causes segmentation fault
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: What's the value of 'i'?

Comment: You should throw away whatever source taught you to use malloc here.

Comment: Or drop the ever quirky C++ for a real language ;). Just kidding.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Avoid using `malloc` with objects in C++.

Instead, use `new`:

```
std::string * str = new std::string("Hello");
// ...
delete str;
```

For an array:

```
std::string * tab = new std::string[5];
// ...
delete[] tab; // if you allocated with new[], release with delete[]
```

The reason it's failing in this case is that `malloc`, unlike `new`, does not call the class' constructor. Since `std::string` allocates memory on its own, then you get an invalid object in the end.

So, `new`/`delete` (or `new[]`/`delete[]`) is the way to go here. You can still use `malloc` if you want, but only for "POD" type (primitive types, old style structs, etc.). And if you allocate with `malloc`, release with `free`. Don't mix up `new` and `free` or `malloc` and `delete` (there's an exception to this rule: see Mehrdad Afshari's comment below).

Comment: You could technically also use `malloc` and call the constructor directly.  But this would be bad, bad, bad.

Comment: @John Yes, but the only good reason I can think off is to allocate a large memory buffer to initialise later, and we got placement new for that.

Comment: Avoid allocating dynamic arrays in C++; use vector.

Comment: Regarding the last paragraph, there's one subtle exception: you can allocate memory with `malloc` and use placement `new` to initialize a class in that memory location. Of course, this technique should be reserved only for special circumstances. For instance, adding `new(pointerToString+i) string;` before the last line will call the constructor for the string class on that memory location. Note that if you do this, you should call destructor manually: `pointerToString[i].~string();` and then use `free` (if you allocated with `malloc`).

Answer (score 5):

```
std::vector<std::string> strings(5);
```

This is what you actually want.

Answer (score 0):

As Etienne said, you should have used **new** as malloc only allocates memory but does not call constructor which initializes that memory. std::string is a class and when you want to create instance of it on the heap, you must use **new**, just like for any other class type. 
You tried to write to a wrong address and therefore your segmentation fault.

You want to create array of strings. In C, you will use array, but in C++ use std::vector.

Answer (score 0):

You probably do not want to be doing it that way but if you are, i.e. using malloc to allocate the memory, then you need to use placement-new.

Actually, this will do placement-new for you.

```
std::vector< std::string > vec;
vec.reserve( 5 );
vec.resize( 5 );
```

The call to reserve() allocates the memory for you and then resize() actually creates the objects there in the memory already allocated, with placement-new.

[Placement new in the C++ FAQ](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/dtors.html#faq-11.10) is documented well here. Read it to learn. Then probably simply use vector.